# How to change browser title dynamically in joomla page?

Tags: php, joomla

i am developing job portal for that I am using joomla, i want to change browser tab title dynamically, for that iam using a page showjob  and i passed job id through url to that page but joomla showing showjob as browser title but i don't want that , i need job title as browser tab title. for this what i did is

1.Created a menu item 'showjob'

2.Created a module 'showjob'

3.Assigned menu for 'showjob' module to 'showjob' menu item only

4.the 'showjob' module is a 'flexi custom php module' here i  wrote databse connections and other stuff in php

5.the job id 'jid' passed through url from another module like www.example.com/jid=1;

6.in 'showjob' module i received it as $_GET['jid'] and retrieved the data as like $row['jtitle']; etc

7.Now i want that title as showjob page browser title

Comment: Please let us know what have tried yet. Try adding your sample code as well

Comment: <title>My title</title> whats wrong with that?

Comment: i edited my content for further clarification

Comment: @GowrisankarVeluturla, that is only possible if you redirect it to new page with `<a>` as module is just a section of a page, which is why it is not dependent on url

Comment: @Ms. Nehal is there any possibility to dynamically change browser title

Comment: @GowrisankarVeluturla, how you want it to be done, just as page loads ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your Question 100%.

What if you try the following within the Flexi Custom PHP Module

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle($row['jtitle']);
```

https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getDocument

Comment: @GowrisankarVeluturla - Glad it worked, you may accept my answer as the solution

Answer (score 0):

So,
I tried editing the title dynamically by creating a database with the page id's and the title name in a database and then calling the table and getting the queries. I successfully pulled it off.
I Edited the head.php file using this code.

```html
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$foo = $jinput->get('id');

$query1 = $db

    ->getQuery(true)

    ->select(array('*'))

    ->from($db->quoteName('#__page_title'))

    ->where($db->quoteName('page_id') . " = " . $db->quote($foo));

$db->setQuery($query1);

$results = $db->loadAssocList();

foreach ($results as $itemdata)  {
  $page_title = $itemdata["page_title"];
}

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$this->setTitle( $this->getTitle() . ' - ' . $page_title);
```

Add this before this line of code
$this->addHead();
Do let me know if this works for you!